# Analysis/report of a simulation study on the level of parameters or on the level of replications?

Tags: r, simulation, psychometrics, confirmatory-factor, item-response-theory

I conduct a simulation study in which I generate data from a specific model, fit that model to the generated data, and repeat that $R$ times. The model that I work with (in my case it's an IRT model, but that doesn't matter much), has multiple parameters of the same type. For example, it has $N$ person parameters, one for each person (e.g., the persons' ability).

When summarizing the results, I feel like I have two options.

1. I may look at each of the $R$ runs separately, calculate the statistic I'm interested in (e.g., mean bias), and then pool the results across runs (e.g., make a box plot of $R$ mean bias values).

   The focus of this option is on a generated data set, it's the perspective of a researcher with a single sample at hand, variability is smaller here.
2. I may look at all $R * N$ estimates simultaneously, calculate the statistic I'm interested in (e.g., bias), and then describe the result (e.g., make a box plot of $R*N$ bias values).

   The focus here is on the parameter itself, variability is larger here; but why not doing a single sample with $R*N$ persons in the first place. Moreover, it may well be that this means correlating (or scatter plotting) pairs of 1,000,000 or even more values.

I feel lost in deciding which route to take. Papers I looked at seem to go with option (2). (Please comment if you have an illustrative example of the first option).

The outcomes that I'm actually interested in are (a) correlation of true and observed value, (b) bias, and (c) RMSE. The purpose of my work is to study the recovery of the model parameters when fitting the correct model (or when fitting a misspecified model).

So the question is how should I summarize the results of my simulation study.

---

### Appendix

Here is a MWE in `R`, which is not critical for the question, but which may clarify things or may be used to play around with.

```
install.packages("eRm")
install.packages("reshape2")
reps <- 100
N <- 100
J <- 10
res <- rep(list(as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = N, ncol = 2,
                                     dimnames = list(NULL, c("true", "obs"))))), reps)
for (iii in seq_len(reps)) {
    ppar <- rnorm(N)                # true parameters
    X <- eRm::sim.rasch(ppar, J)    # generate data
    m1 <- eRm::RM(X)                # fit model
    res[[iii]][, "true"] <- ppar
    res[[iii]][, "obs"] <- eRm::person.parameter(m1)$theta.table$`Person Parameter`
}
res2 <- reshape2::melt(res, id.vars = c("true", "obs"))

### Option 1 ###
# Bias
mean(sapply(by(res2, res2$L1, function(x) x$obs - x$true), mean))
boxplot(sapply(by(res2, res2$L1, function(x) x$obs - x$true), mean))
# Cor
mean(by(res2, res2$L1, function(x) cor(x$obs, x$true)))
boxplot(by(res2, res2$L1, function(x) cor(x$obs, x$true)))

### Option 2 ###
# Bias
mean(res2$obs - res2$true)          # mean bias identical to (1) of course
boxplot(res2$obs - res2$true)
# Cor
cor(res2$obs, res2$true)
plot(res2$obs, res2$true)
```

Comment: Any idea for a better title/framing of this question?

Comment: Are the parameters for a person the same in each replication? Say... does N1 in R1 have the same parameters as N1 in R2?

Comment: No, they are completely independent. A new, random sample is generated in each replication.

Comment: So there is no difference between 2 replications of N = 100 and 1 replication of N = 200?

Comment: Well, if you only look at the generated person parameters, there is no difference between (a) generating 100 two times and (b) generating 200 and randomly dividing into two subsamples. Apart from that, it does make a difference: More persons make certain estimates more accurate (consistency) and, from an applied perspective, N = 1,000 is reasonable but N = 1,000,000 is not.

Comment: There is a lot of literature on the 'batch means' method for estimating parameter values.  There are caveats but it does allow you to implement the central limit theorem which makes analysis easier.